# swiper js doesnt set on horizontal mode properly

Tags: next.js13, swiper.js

I want to use swiperjs on horizontal mode (As I read before it default mode is horizontal). here is my code :

```
<Swiper
          slidesPerView={slidesPerView}
          breakpoints={{
            300: {
              slidesPerView: 1,
              spaceBetween: 10,
            },
            600: {
              slidesPerView: 1,
              spaceBetween: 10,
            },
            // when window width is >= 480px
            700: {
              slidesPerView,
              spaceBetween: 20,
            },
          }}
          modules={[Pagination, Navigation]}
          navigation={true}
          className={styles.slideContainer}
          // autoplay={{
          //   delay: 2500,
          //   disableOnInteraction: false,
          // }}
        >
          {specialData?.data?.map((item, index) => {
            if (item.thumbnail_cover_image != null)
              return (
                <SwiperSlide key={index}>
                  <Image
                              fill
                              src={`${baseSpecialImageUrl}${item.thumbnail_cover_image}`}
                            />
                </SwiperSlide>
              );
          })}
        </Swiper>
```

But it doesnt work propery on horizontal mode . and shows image vertically .

[image]

my project is next.js 13.5 and my swiper js version is 11.0.5